# How do you prepare an image for a double truck (spread) in a magazine?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to find a best practice for preparing an image for a double truck or spread of a magazine. My assumption (if the image is equal on both pages) is to split the file in half...for the left hand file, extend the right side the amount of compensation for the binding (3/16" in this case) and then to clone the edge outward toward the edge. Repeating the same process for the right toward the left edge. Can anyone tell me if this is correct and has anyone seen a plug-in that does this?

Comment: In a facing pages InDesign document, you just place a single image over the gutter. Then export to PDF/X-1a with bleeds. Done. You certainly wouldn't need to break the image into multiple files. Not certain why you'd use Photoshop for this at all.

Comment: Hi chad, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score -2):

You can use photoshop with indesign to success this in a short time.

Process:
- learn the size of spread and one page from indesign.
- create a photoshop work with that size.
- in photoshop create a new guide with %50 vertical.
- calculate that specific size for left section. And clone it.